# How to have numeric keyboard popup to input in TextBox on Windows Mobile 6.53? (C++ vs2008)

Tags: visual-c++, windows-mobile

How to have numeric keyboard popup to input in TextBox on Windows Mobile 6.53? (C++ vs2008)

When one clicks in a text box, the numeric keypad should popup - not the full keyboard.

I searched for other threads, but a solution does not seem to exist. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183783(v=vs.90).aspx)

This code fails - it does not bring up the numeric keypad, but the full qwerty keyboard:

```
hwndCtl = GetDlgItem(hwndDlg, IDC_PASSWORD);

SHSetImeMode(hwndCtl, SHIME_MODE_NUMBERS);
```

This does not compile - it does not recognize Microsoft.WindowsCE.Forms (I am unable to find the header file to include for this, if it exists):

```
Microsoft.WindowsCE.Forms::InputModeEditor.SetInputMode(hwndCtl,Microsoft.WindowsCE.Forms.InputMode.Numeric);
```

error C2065: 'Microsoft' : undeclared identifier

Is there a way to do this without writing my own dialog?

Comment: Define "fails" and elaborate on "does not compile".  you get errors?  What errors?

Comment: @ctacke, I clarified with added text - thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating my own numeric keypad since I did not receive any replies for a long time.

Comment: Any chance you can share your numeric keypad code?  We are facing a similar issue and that would be a great timesaver.

Comment: I would willingly give it to you but the problem is, I don't own the code that I write. I would have to ask my manager for permission.

Comment: If you can ask, that would be great.  If they say no, I fully understand.  Thanks!

Comment: Here is an example of a numeric keypad with fully open source that you can use as a basis http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11518/Pocket-PC-Numeric-Key-Pad

Answer (score 2):

You have the right idea, you're just missing the right import statement.

According to the documentation for [InputModeEditor.SetInputMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsce.forms.inputmodeeditor.setinputmode%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

> Specifies the input mode on a Smartphone.
>   ...
>   You can set the input mode only on a TextBox.

Its example, however, is too terse. However, according to [the documentation for InputModeEditor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsce.forms.inputmodeeditor%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), here's what you need to do:

```
using Microsoft.WindowsCE.Forms;
...
hwndCtl = GetDlgItem(hwndDlg, IDC_PASSWORD);
InputModeEditor.SetInputMode(hwndCtl,InputMode.Numeric);
```

To access members from the namespace you desire, you have to use it.

[This documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172542%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) may also help you.

Comment: Thanks for replying (I upvoted you), but I ended up creating my own numeric keypad since I did not receive any replies for a long time. :)

Comment: @Anil I don't know if this answer is correct, but it doesn't really matter if you chose to abandon the whole question and just ignore the problem. This doesn't magically make a correct answer non-acceptable. It's not about what you end up with after giving up on the whole problem, but about what corectly answers the question.

Comment: @MrGomez, Sorry but that does not work. Lots of compile errors. error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '.' error C2873: 'Microsoft' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration error C2059: syntax error : '.'

Comment: @Anil Ah! The problem here is these are C# symbols, and you appear to be using them with plain Visual C++ (as you've tagged). I apologize for my original misunderstanding of your intent and encourage you to use the solution that is, at least presently, working for you. :)

Comment: @MrGomez, do you know how one can increase the size of the sip keyboard? (vc++, windows mobile 6.53). the keys are so tiny on the default sip.

Comment: @Anil I see [your question on this subject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10014275/how-to-increase-size-of-sip-qwerty-keyboard-on-windows-mobile-6-53-vc). I admit that I did not off the top of my head, but I did find [this discussion](http://www.itlisting.org/4-windows-ce-embedded/1a533488fc7d82da.aspx) and [this sample chapter on the subject!](https://www.microsoft.com/mspress/books/sampchap/5461b.aspx) If this works for you, I'll go back to your question and answer it. :)

Comment: @MrGomez, Thanks for the links - I read them but could not figure out how to increase the size of the SIP panel from the default 80 pixels to something larger. I found this SIP sample but it does not set the size C:\Program Files\Windows Mobile 6 SDK\Samples\PocketPC\CPP\win32\HandleSIP

Comment: I dont know how people use it - the keys are so tiny, that even with a stylus, one ends up typing the wrong keys.