# How to increase size of sip qwerty keyboard on windows mobile 6.53? (VC++)

Tags: visual-c++, windows-mobile-6.5

In an input text field, the user taps at the Soft Input Panel keyboard to bring it up. Unfortunately, the keys are so tiny! Is there a way from VC++ (VS2008) to resize it so the buttons are larger?

I dont know how people use it - the keys are so tiny, that even with a stylus, one ends up typing the wrong keys. I could not figure out how to increase the size of the SIP panel from the default 80 pixels to something larger. I found this SIP sample but it does not set the size C:\Program Files\Windows Mobile 6 SDK\Samples\PocketPC\CPP\win32\HandleSIP

Comment: Is there no way to do this? there should be a simple setSize();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not simple, but you can provide a custom Soft Input Panel (SIP).

MSDN has an article titled [Programming a Software-Based Input Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa929815.aspx) that details the technique.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I am trying to simply set the size of the panel; seems like such a basic feature.

Comment: To my knowledge, the only way to do what you want is to create a custom panel.

Comment: I up-voted you, but need to see if the method I was looking for, is possible.